# can I run multiple DataFrames and apply a function to each list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

i got 18 merged lists

```
tempNew_1 = pd.merge(temp1, temp1_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_2 = pd.merge(temp2, temp2_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_3 = pd.merge(temp3, temp3_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_4 = pd.merge(temp4, temp4_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_5 = pd.merge(temp5, temp5_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_6 = pd.merge(temp6, temp6_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_7 = pd.merge(temp7, temp7_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_8 = pd.merge(temp8, temp8_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_9 = pd.merge(temp9, temp9_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_10 = pd.merge(temp10, temp10_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_11 = pd.merge(temp11, temp11_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_12 = pd.merge(temp12, temp12_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_13 = pd.merge(temp13, temp13_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_14 = pd.merge(temp14, temp14_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_15 = pd.merge(temp15, temp15_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_16 = pd.merge(temp16, temp16_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_17 = pd.merge(temp17, temp17_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
tempNew_18 = pd.merge(temp18, temp18_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

is it possible to apply this funcion to any DataFrame and overwritte them ?

```
def filter_outlier(x):
### FILTER DATA ###
# folgend wird ein numpyarray erstellt das den z-Score jedes Wertes in temp1
z_scores_x = stats.zscore(x)
abs_x = np.abs(z_scores_x)
filtered_x = (abs_x < 3)
new_y = x[filtered_x]
return new_y
```

I am grateful for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your dataframes `temp1`, `temp2`, etc. and `temp1_t`, `temp2_t` into separate lists. Do this when you originally create the dataframes, not after they are already separate df's. So they would look like:

   ```py
   temps = [temp1, temp2, ..., temp18]
   temp_ts = [temp1_t, temp2_t, ..., temp18_t]
   ```

   Note that each item in the lists is a dataframe.
2. Then create a list of your merged df's using a loop and [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a list comprehension:

   ```py
   news = [pd.merge(t, t_t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
           for (t, t_t) in zip(temps, temp_ts)]
   ```
3. Then call your `filter_outlier()` function with each item in `news`:

   ```py
   filtered = [filter_outlier(df) for df in news]
   ```

   If you want to overwrite the existing merged df's, then assign it back to the same list `news`:

   ```py
   news = [filter_outlier(df) for df in news]
   ```

Btw, `news` in step 2 could be made a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=generator#generator-expressions) so that it's not created in memory and the items are only created and processed when creating `filtered`.

In all 3 steps, you'll be accessing the dataframes in the lists using indexes or standard iteration. There's no need to create 18 variables for each step.